# Node exporter port already in use, service is failed

Tags: linux, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Node exporter is in failed state, journalctl says:

```
level=fatal msg="listen tcp :9100: bind: address already in use" source="node_exporter.go:114"
```

I tried `reset-failed` and restarting the service still the same issue. Then i listed processes using 9100 port and killed the process (the process was a node_exporter process) but right after i kill it whether normally or with -9 it just starts a new process as a result my 9100 port is always in use and can't start node_exporter because of it. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn process-id of process, who use port 9100

   `netstat -lpn | grep 9100`
2. Learn parent pid of process

   `ps -p PID -o ppid`
3. If parent process is **systemd**(pid is 1), then find its service name via

   `systemctl status PID`

   And decide what to do with it.
   If parent process is **not** systemd, but something like **containerd-shim**, this means that this process is managed via Kubernetes Daemonset.
   In such case you need to decide to reuse existing process, or to change port in your node_exporter.service, you may add `--web.listen-address=:9101` to ExecStart property in your service manifest and apply `systemctl daemon-reload`, then restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found a solution:

search the process that uses 9100 port:

```
ss -ntpl 9100
```

look what PID of process and then kill him:

```
kill <pid>
```

Also, remember about node taints and tolerations